# Can an integer $0\leq n<10$ be described as a double-digit number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is it considered mathematically sound to write the number "7" as "07", for example?

Some context: I'm trying to write a riddle in which the solver has to guess a four digit number $n$. For example, let $n = 2503$. Would it be "fair" to say that the last two digits of $n$ are a prime number? If not, can you think of any better ways to phrase this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. All of the following notate the integer seven:

- $7$
- $07$
- $\ldots00007$
- $007.000$
- $0007.000000\ldots$
- $\ldots007.00\ldots$
- $006.9999\ldots$

Under common definitions of what "decimal" really means, all of these but the last are actually the same *decimal* as well: all decimals are implicitly infinite in both directions, with $0$'s filling every position that hasn't been explicitly indicated.

(in the above, the ellipses indicate that the indicated pattern continues without terminating)

However, we usually would not call $07$ a double-digit number. I think most would agree it's a double-digit *numeral*, though.

P.S. be careful if you are a programmer or work with computer algebra systems -- some adopt a convention where having 0 as a leading numeral changes the meaning of the digits. e.g. the `C` programming language will read `0####` as being octal -- a number written in base 8 rather than base 10. i.e. in the `C` programming language, `013` is the integer eleven.

P.P.S. You meant $0 \leq n < 10$! Although it's clear what you meant here, you should be careful to remember to put lower bounds when you intend them: it's easy to confuse yourself when solving algebra problems if you aren't habitually careful about what you mean.

Comment: I'm kicking myself for that bound error. I've corrected it for clarity. Thanks for this truly comprehensive answer!